# Here map offline implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, maps, here-api

I am making an android application currently that will use "Here map SDK" for offline map navigation. I have  followed the documentation given in **https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html** But I am having problem on its Implementation.

Q:
Can Anyone provide me the demo application that has successful implementation on "Offline Maps (MapLoader)"  of Here Map SDK?

Comment: I know another api that you can use to view offline maps but it doesn't relate to the Here Maps API instead its the mapbox sdk

Comment: -Shariq Musharaf: thank u for your suggestion but i need to use the here map SDk for my application.

Answer (score 3):

There is an official HERE example exactly for that usecase (offline mapdata download, update and checking for updates) on https://tcs.ext.here.com/mobilesdk_examples

Direct links:

- Android: https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/MapDownloader.zip
- iOS: https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/OfflineMaps.zip

Comment: Thanks Marco.. How can I change the map data to be downloaded on my app. For eg: I dont want to download the map data of berlin but i want to download the map data of "New York"??

Comment: MapLoader.getInstance().getMapPackages() will result in a callback (so register for the listener in MapLoader) onGetMapPackagesComplete that contains a list of available mappackages in a linked list (see https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-odml-mappackage.html#topic-apiref and esp. the getChildren method). Either offer the full list for selection in your app or you as a developer go through that liste one time and pick the right mappackage/id you need (in my example I hardcoded the berlin package)

Comment: I have successfully installed `MapPackage`. Now what could be the step for use offline map that user want to. I am asking for is any method like setoffline or setonline for `MapFragment`?

Comment: In the MapEngine instance you can call setOnline(Boolean) - see: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-mapengine.html#topic-apiref__setonline-boolean

Comment: @Marco thank you :)  one more question if no map is downloded and  `MapEngine.setOnline(false)` than sometime data is getting from request. in this case error should be thrown. can you show with small demo of MapEngine with offline maps?

Comment: @AkashPatel how to get ID of suppose map of India? when I used getchildren it returned me some Ids but how to know which is of India?

Comment: @MrunalAhirrao In for loop print `mapPackage.getChildren().get(i).getEnglishTitle()` and `mapPackage.getChildren().get(i).getId()` together.

Comment: @AkashPatel Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

you can find example code with the sdk itself still you can look at the following links

[heremaps Examples](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/)

[android example heremap](https://github.com/PauloLuan/here-maps-android-example)