# Android - Here Premium Sdk Offline Map

Tags: android, dictionary, sdk, offline

I have reread the documentation so many times. But I couldn't managed to do so I just wanted to ask your help.

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html

I implemented listener and started with:

```
MapLoader.Listener mapLoaderListener = new MapLoader.Listener() {
public void onUninstallMapPackagesComplete(MapPackage rootMapPackage,
 MapLoader.ResultCode mapLoaderResultCode) {  
  }
     public void onProgress(int progressPercentage) {
  }
  public void onPerformMapDataUpdateComplete(MapPackage rootMapPackage,
     MapLoader.ResultCode mapLoaderResultCode) {
  }
  public void onInstallationSize(long diskSize, long networkSize) {
  }
  public void onInstallMapPackagesComplete(MapPackage rootMapPackage,
      MapLoader.ResultCode mapLoaderResultCode) {
  }
  public void onGetMapPackagesComplete(MapPackage rootMapPackage,
      MapLoader.ResultCode mapLoaderResultCode) {   // İ put break point and look inside of rootMapPackage to get ids
  }
  public void onCheckForUpdateComplete(boolean updateAvailable,
    String currentMapVersion,String newestMapVersion,
          MapLoader.ResultCode mapLoaderResultCode) {
  }
};

MapLoader mapLoader = MapLoader.getInstance();
mapLoader.addListener(mapLoaderListener);
mapLoader.getMapPackages(); //after this code executed i look inside the
                            //variables in rootMapPackage and i get ids .

mapLoader.installMapPackages(idlist);
```

after installationMapPackages program goes into

```
public void onInstallMapPackagesComplete(MapPackage rootMapPackage,
                                        MapLoader.ResultCode mapLoaderResultCode)
```

According to the documentation I think I should have managed to download and install map packages for offline usage but nothing happens. And the installation process takes at most 20 seconds. So I think nothing happens. I search the problem on the internet but everyone just directed to people to the this documentation page but obviously it is not enough (at least i didn't managed to do). How should process be?

Thank You

Comment: Hope this link helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930459/here-map-offline-implementation

Comment: I don't know if it's because sdk update but . Now it's working. I was kinda doing something with your link but i got help from it. Thank you.