# Downloading Offiline Maps using here maps sdk through the searched places

Tags: android, maps, here-api

I am developing an application using here maps that will download the offline maps when i type the name of the place in the search bar. Right now i am only able to download the map by manually adding the id of the places and download it. But i need to download the maps of searched places  by getting id of the map packages automatically. 
How can i generate the map package Id automatically when the user type the place name and use it to download the maps?

Answer (score 0):

The IDs are fixed numbers so you can safely cache them. You will need to call the map loader APIs to first retrieve the package tree, copy the data structure as member variables and then use the cached IDs when the user types in a country / state.

Comment: David Leong Can u please provide me some code for that,,,

Comment: Hope think link helps to achieve your requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930459/here-map-offline-implementation